# Can't find a valid editor for this file extension

Tags: dreamweaver

I've changed Extensions.txt in

```
Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CS5.5\Configuration
```

And I've changed MMDocumentTypes.xml in

```
Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CS5.5\Configuration\Document Types
```

But I'm still getting "Can't find a valid editor for this file extension".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

```
 in dreamwaver just go to
 Edit > Preferences > File Types/Editors
 you will find .js .asa .css .inc .txt .as .asc .asr .htaccess .htpasswd
 add your extension at the end to be like this
 .js .asa .css .inc .txt .as .asc .asr .htaccess .htpasswd .lng
 my additional extension here was .lng file.
 it really saved me a lot of time.thanks
```

Answer (score 3):

> in dreamwaver just go to  Edit > Preferences > File Types/Editors 
>   you will find .js .asa .css .inc .txt .as .asc .asr .htaccess
>   .htpasswd  add your extension at the end to be like this

This worked like a charm. Wish I would have found this two hours ago.

Answer (score 2):

Dreamweaver's configuration work with the user folder taking precedence. Typically, at least one of the files that you mention have copies in the user's configuration folder. So if they are present they will be used not the ones in the application configuration folder.

The Adobe technote that describes how to add a file extensions ( http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16410.html ) lists the user configuration folder under the edits to the Extensions.txt file. Also, while that technote states to edit the MMDocumentTypes.xml file in the application folder, make sure you don't have a copy in your user folder. There are some circumstances where there will be a copy in the user folder and if so, you have to make changes to the user configuration folder copy, not the application configuration folder version.